# overflow in bootstrap table

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to overflow my table.

```
-----------------------
|  name  |  height  |
-----------------------
| john   |  5,8     ^
| josh   |  6,4     |
| joshua |  5,4     |
| jon    |  5,5     V
-----------------------
```

I used overflow-y:scroll;
But I want is, only the table body is scrolling. I want is like my example above.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-responsive">
<thead>
  <tr>
    ...
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   ...
  </tr>
  <tr>
   ...
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Is it possible to overflow only the table body part? I am using bootstrap.

Comment: what you have tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way:

Add two tables say tabel1 and table2 in one table.
now include table headers in table1 and table body in table2.
use `style="overflow:auto;"` or `style="overflow:scroll;"` for table2.

Answer (score 0):

i found this solution that works

```
<table class="table table-striped">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>header1</th>
            <th>header2</th>
            <th>header3</th>
            <th>header4</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>Column1</td>
            <td>Column2</td>
            <td>Column3</td>
            <td>Column4</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>
```

and this css

```
table {
    width: 100%;
}

thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

tr:after {
    content: ' ';
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    clear: both;
}


tbody {
    height: 200px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

thead {
    /* fallback */
}


tbody td, thead th {
    width: 20%;
    float: left;
}
```

you can see a demo here[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/XJ8jrLbuDr)